# Get array values and show separated by space as class name (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to show as class name in a div the array values separates by space like this: `class="item 23 54 77"`
I only can obtain the values separated with comma in the current code.
any idea? i was trying with `str_replace` and nothing..
thx!

```
var selectedTags = new Array();

$("input[name=tags]:checked").each(function() {
    selectedTags'.($set_id).'.push(this.value);
});

$("#step_box").removeClass().addClass("item "+selectedTags,function(){});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a space as delimiter.

When you try to concatenate string with array the js engine casts it to string using  [`Array#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) which includes comma separators

```
$("#step_box").removeClass().addClass("item "+selectedTags.join(' '));
```

---

Or Just add each one without using the array

```
var $step = $("#step_box").removeClass().addClass('item');
$("input[name=tags]:checked").each(function() {
    $step.addClass(this.value);
});
```